# Cannot use import statement outside a module when trying to import tensorflow.js into browser app

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, npm, import

I am following [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tfjs-training-regression/index.html#1) basic tutorial for TensorFlow.js. In the tutorial they use script tags but I wanted to use npm to install tensorflow and import it:

- I ran `npm install @tensorflow/tfjs` like explained [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/setup) which worked
- I tried to import it like so: `import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';`

Getting the following mistake (as in the title): `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`
I am new to using npm so might just be a stupid beginner mistake.

Tried this:

- When searching for this problem something that came up quite often was that I had to add `"type": "module"` in the `package.json` so I ran `npm init` to create a `package.json` and then did as told:

```
{
  "name": "tensorflow",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Testing out tensorflow (following a tutorial)",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  ...
}
```

- still getting the same mistake.
- I am using the script in which im trying to import tensorflow in an html file so I even tried this which didn't even make any sense to me:

  ```
    <script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
  ```

now getting this mistake: `Access to script at 'file:///***/tensorflow/index.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https. index.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED`

Some additional info (don't know if relevant, probably not):

- I am using Visual Studio Code running/debugging the html page with the default Chrome-Debugging config.
- Node Version: v12.16.3

Help much appreciated.

Edit:
Running the script with Node works though:

- I installed tensorflow for node: `npm install @tensorflow/tfjs-node`
- "Import" it:

  ```
    const tf = require("@tensorflow/tfjs");
    require("@tensorflow/tfjs-node");
  ```
- No error there

Comment: Are you trying to use this in a Node.js script or in a web page? What version of Node.js are you running? What's the result of `node -v`?

Comment: @Trott In a web page. (See [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tfjs-training-regression/index.html#1) tutorial) Node version: v12.16.3